# Submit form from Android App direct to SMS

Tags: android, forms, sms

I would like to have a submit button send the content of a related form directly to a phone number via SMS.  However, the phone number should be private.  Can the number be encoded?

Comment: How you will be sending the SMS? If its through server(SMS gateways) than you can but if its through device than if cann`t be possible

Comment: Even if I wasn't able to encode, how would I send the SMS with a submit button in code (by carrying over the from data into the SMS automatically)?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your requirements ? You can handle a button event and on that event you can call service(for sending SMS), for this service you have to defined receipent mobile number for sending SMS. So at what part your question is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your submit button's onClick handler needs to do something like this:

1. Go through all relevant views in your activity and fetch the current values.
2. Create a text string from the values.
3. Create a SMS message with the text string as its message body and send to your server.

Use [android.telephony.SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) to send SMS messages. Be aware that your app needs special permissions to do this.

Here is a tutorial that shows how to do all of this: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android.